# Unable to upate ListView data

Tags: android

I have a class A which extends Activity. From the class A ,I am calling Adapter class B which extends BaseAdapter.

I am displaying ListView data from within the overriden method 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

I am fetching the data for the ListView from SQLite. Now on clicking on a cancel button for a specific listitem , I am able to delete the record the data from the database , but unable to refresh the view . Still the data is being displayed . But if again I navigate to the screen from the home screen , the data is not being displayed , indicating there is no problem with the database , only updating display is a issue .

The skeletal code is as follows:

```
class A extends Activity {

    B adapter ;
    ListView list ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.textList);
        // I am calling the adapter

        adapter = new B(this, txtStr);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class B extends BaseAdapter{
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            // on click of the delete button , record is delated for a specific
            // listitem & the view needs to be updated , but I am unable to update the view

            holder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private int pos = position;
                    public void onClick(View v) {// (position)) -- what was this doing here? (dbreslau)

                        sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where id = 1");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**Even after calling the notifyDataSetChanged , the view is not getting updated.
Kindly help if anyone already implemented the same.**

Comment: I just made an attempt at fixing your code formatting, and discovered some syntax errors (see the note at the out-of-position `(position))` .) I'm not sure if the code is integral enough to analyze.

Comment: The Listview displays list of items . Consider every list item containing 2 image buttons like Delete & Add . When a user clicks on a specific button of a list item , position helps in determining the particular list item . I am aware of the onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id), from where we get the position . How can I handle if the user clicks on Add or Delete button of any list item . Kindly help since I am still unable to update the view after deleting a list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your onClickListener out of your adapter, in the activity class, since you're creating new listener for each view constructed, then in the onClickListener onClick method just do this:

```
    class A extends Activity {

                B adapter ;
                ListView list ;

                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.textList);
                    // I am calling the adapter

                    adapter = new B(this, txtStr);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    list.setOnItemClickListener (listener);
                }


private OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where id = 1");
         //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         ((B)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

    **EDIT 1** 
    //with an onCLickListener...
    private OnClickListener deleteListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int)v.getTag();
                            sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where id = 1");
                            ((B)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged());
            }
        };


                class B extends BaseAdapter{
                    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

                        // on click of the delete button , record is delated for a specific
                        // listitem & the view needs to be updated , but I am unable to update the view

    holder.deleteImage.setTag(position);                   
    holder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);
    //...
    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Franco for the reply .  Actually , if I use OnItemClick , then clicking on a specific list item , how to get the position of the list item . Also , within each list item there are multiple Image icons like Delete , Add , so how can I differentiate betweek the Delete & Add button click .  Kindly advice

Comment: int position = (int)v.getTag();   this line gives error "Cannot cast from Object to int"

Comment: i didn´t try, i wrote in the browser, but this works 
int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

Comment: int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()); //the statement provides an error

Comment: very very strange, i do that in the same way, setting the list item position as tag and getting in my listener, and works fine

Comment: even , I hardcoded the position as 0 for the first list item , but the screen doesnot refresh & the list item still persists. If I go back to the previous screen & then navigate to the screen , now I get an empty screen which is fine . But when I actually delete the item , the screen doesnot update . I used the notifyDataChanged as adviced. I want the screen to refresh when the data is removed i.e the entire list item should be invisible since the entire data from the row is deleted. Kindly provide your comments.

Comment: can you provide the BaseAdapter construct? where do you pass the data from sqlite db?

Comment: public B(Activity a, String[] d) { activity = a; data = d; inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext()); } //data is the image data ... actually I am asynchronously loading images for each list item ... Database query is working fine ... since when I go back to the previous screen & navigate to list screen , the deleted data is not displayed . I want to refresh the listview screen as soon as the data is deleted which is not happening currently. ImageLoader class used for loading images

Comment: you have to delete both data, from Database and from data element (the data element you pass through constructor) because i suspect that you build your views and items with the String[] data. If you only delete your item from the database and the adapter builds this items with String[] data, then the adapter never knows that the data change until you restart your activity, later call notifyDataSetChanged()...

Comment: thanks a lot friend ... after restarting the activity its done :)    I have another query ... already posted but without any proper answer .. if you are interested to solve that ... can provide the details of the question

Comment: ok, my appologies, the code above works for me but i dont figure how to fit to your actual schema, so , i'll be implement something like your adapter to get the answer

Comment: thanks a lot ... write now , the code is working ... am able to update listview ... I have posted another question long time back without any straight forward answer .. I'm struggling for 3 weeks ...if you want I can provide the question details